# Counting the votes of items listed in an array_ python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, while-loop

There is a party and each and every person must write the fruit they want and by doing this they are also voting. After that the fruits should be printed and the number of votes(the number of times it appeared).

Sample input

Enter the names of parties (terminated by DONE):

apples

oranges

oranges

oranges

pears

bananas

bananas

kiwis

oranges

apples

oranges

DONE

---

Sample output

Vote counts:

apples - 2

bananas - 2

kiwis - 1

oranges - 5

pears - 1

```
a = []
print("Enter the names of parties (terminated by DONE):")
item = input()
while not item == "DONE" : 
    if item not in a: 
        a.append(item)
    item = input()
a = sorted(a)
print()
print("Vote counts:")
for i in a:
    print(i,"-",counts)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: which function am i using to count?

Comment: `from collections import Counter`, then `Counter(a)` will give you the results you want, albeit in a slightly different format.

Comment: error : cannot import name 'counter'

Comment: Python is a case sensitive language

Comment: everywhere its printing 1 vote

Comment: @Dj_Casoko - It's only printing one because you don't allow items to be added multiple times as you filter out those entries using the line `if item not in a:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You couldn't `import Counter` because you wrote "counter", with a lowercase "C".

in your code, with this line

```
if item not in a: 
    a.append(item)
```

You are only adding to the list items which aren't there, so you will get maximum count of 1 whatever.
**Perhaps this is what you are looking for:**

```
from collections import Counter
fruit_list = []
item = ""
while True:
    item = input("Enter the names of parties (terminated by DONE): ")
    if item == "DONE":
        break
    else:
        print("You have chosen: {}".format(item))
        fruit_list.append(item)
        my_count = Counter(fruit_list)

for key,value in my_count.items():
    print("\n{:<10} has been chosen {:<2}{:<2} times.".format(key,"",value))
```